# AudioKit 4.0 AKPeriodicFunctions Not Starting

Tags: audiokit

Unable to start AK4 AKPeriodic function in XCode 9. In the following excerpt from the "Plucked String" playground, I inserted two log messages to help identify processing events. I never see the "periodic function startup" message in the console log. All I hear is a very short clicking sound.

```
let scale = [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12]
let performance = AKPeriodicFunction(frequency: playRate) {
    print("periodic function startup")
    var note = scale.randomElement()
    let octave = [2, 3, 4, 5].randomElement() * 12
    if random(0, 10) < 1.0 { note += 1 }
    if !scale.contains(note % 12) { print("ACCIDENT!") }

    let frequency = (note + octave).midiNoteToFrequency()
    if random(0, 6) > 1.0 {
        pluckedString.trigger(frequency: frequency)
    }
}

AudioKit.output = reverb
AudioKit.start(withPeriodicFunctions: performance)
print("AK startup")
performance.start()
```

Comment: Working on this today, hopefully I'll post an answer with the fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the develop branch, as per this issue:

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1066

Comment: Any ETA on 4.0.2?

Comment: @sigmonky A few other bugs being fixed this weekend and then we'll make a release.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy turnaround.

Comment: @sigmonkey 4.0.2 is out now and this should be fixed. Onto the next bugs and features...

Comment: Great and thanks! Seeing the 4.0.2 zip archive on the site. But still getting 4.0.1 via Cocoapods. Podspec update pending?

Comment: @sigmonky No actually the podspec was pushed:  
   AudioKit (4.0.2) successfully published
   October 16th, 01:56
   https://cocoapods.org/pods/AudioKit
   Tell your friends!